# Qt example project fails to build (No CMake configuration found)

Tags: cmake, qt6

I am trying to simply open Qt6.4.1 sensors example project, but it says that no CMake configuration found. I already made some simple Qt6 applications for Windows, and i have entire Qt6.4.1 package installed, so cant blame on bad installation. There is an error on line find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Quick Sensors Svg) in CMakeLists.txt. Full error message:

`C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-6.4.1\sensors\sensorsshowcase\CMakeLists.txt:12: error: By not providing "FindQt6.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6" with any of the following names: Qt6Config.cmake qt6-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "Qt6" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt6_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt6" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.`

Comment: Qt 6 is not found. Have you set Qt6_DIR as described in message?

Comment: @usr1234567 Where i can find that?

Comment: `C:\Qt` according to the text you copied. I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the path to the directory containing the Qt6 files via [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) cache variable during configuration.

Note: Make sure to specify the type of the variable as `PATH` or use forward slashes as path separator for this to work properly.

E.g. for me I'd need to pass

```
-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:/Qt/6.4.1/msvc2019_64
```

to tell CMake to look into the directory containing the Qt6.4.1 files compiled with MSVC.

Make sure that the directory you pass contains the file `lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake`; this is the file `find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` is looking for.

You can also fix your project setup that previously failed by adding the cache variable.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:/Qt/6.4.1/msvc2019_64 path/to/build_dir
```

Note: Don't forget to add the `-A ...` option when configuring a VS project; CMake defaults to `Win32` as architecture, at least on my system.

You could add this info to a [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html), if you don't want to specify the info cache variable for every single project using qt 6 that you want to set up on your machine.